# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry.isBeanNameInUse(Ljava/lang/String;)Z

Tags: spring, maven, apache-camel, cxf, jboss-eap-6

Could you help me to resolve this dependency issue? This is a camel integration project which has cxf endpoint invoked inside servlet container.

Upon deploying in the JBoss EAP 6.4, following exception is occurred.

```
Exception: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry.isBeanNameInUse(Ljava/lang/String;)Z`
  <version.maven.compiler.plugin>3.5.1</version.maven.compiler.plugin>
    <jboss.home>${env.JBOSS_HOME}</jboss.home>
    <version.maven.surefire.plugin>2.19.1</version.maven.surefire.plugin>
    <server.config>standalone.xml</server.config>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <version.jboss.bom.eap>6.4.0.GA</version.jboss.bom.eap>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <camel.version>2.17.0.redhat-630224</camel.version>
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cxf.version>3.1.12</cxf.version>
    <version.junit>4.11</version.junit>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <version.maven.war.plugin>2.5</version.maven.war.plugin>
    <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>

<!-- Dependency -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-soap</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-tools-common</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

EDIT: Full Stack trace is at https://pastebin.com/FnDSntN1

EDIT: This issue is resolved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

This unnecessary dependency caused to have non compatible spring jars.

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace.

Comment: @Augusto https://pastebin.com/FnDSntN1

Comment: Please include the stacktrace in the question itself; note that errors like this are usually caused by having inconsistent versions of a dependency. For example, you are using spring 4.3.9.RELEASE, but you explicitly depend on spring-beans 4.1.6.RELEASE, and/or another dependency pulled in an older version of another spring library. I'd start by declaring your spring-beans dependency to also use 4.3.9.RELEASE.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've been trying with different versions of spring-beans by setting versions parameter explicitly. Same exception occurs when I try with same version (4.3.9.RELEASE) as other spring libraries. Sorry for mixing this stuff in the question.